# How can I tell whether a CUDA device has a fixed shared memory bank size?

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

Some CUDA devices support different shared memory bank sizes (4 bytes, 8 bytes); others support just one (typically/always 4 bytes).

As I have come to realize, I *won't* get an error trying to set the bank size to an unsupported value... that will just be ignored. So, how can I tell, programmatically, whether my device is of the first kind or the second kind?

I don't mind using either the runtime or driver APIs.

Comment: Maybe `cudaDeviceGetSharedMemConfig()`? I think it will give you the current config, so maybe it will give you 4 for a device that can support 8 but has 4 set. I guess there is the "hack" option of trying to set it at 8, then get the config, and see if it has changed, as `cudaDeviceSetSharedMemConfig()` "This function will do nothing on devices with fixed shared memory bank size."

Comment: @AnderBiguri: So, you're saying I should just rely on the "do-nothing" behavior... Hmm.

Comment: Well, not saying that you should rely on it, just that that can be an option.... Perhaps there is a more elegant solution, I just don't know about it hehe.

Comment: The only devices that had a modifiable shared memory bank size were [kepler](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared-memory-3-0) devices.  So, programmatically, you can determine that no modification is possible if the compute capabililty major value is greater than 3.  You can also observe that support for Kepler is [starting to disappear](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#deprecated-features).  So maybe the right thing to do is pretend this whole concept doesn't exist, for any new code designs/new work.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: Well, I can't make that assumption in my API wrappers; at least not yet. But if it's just Keplers, I could perhaps check the device architecture.